# SAML SSO: keeping users logged in after validating the SAML Assertion

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I am implementing front-channel SAML 2.0 SSO golang Service Provider, with Okta as my Identity Provider (this is just a POC and should eventually work with any IdP).

Implementing the sign on process was straightforward with [saml2](http://github.com/russellhaering/gosaml2) package. I've created the login endpoint that redirects to the SAML application login URL at the intended IdP, as well as the POST callback endpoint which is properly receiving the SAML assertion and is able to validate it. After that a `session` with a random cookie is created with the same TTL as the Identity Provider session TTL. So far everything works well (I haven't implemented Single Sign-Out yet, but I'm planning to).

However, when some time passes and the session expires, I'd like to renew it **only if the user is still logged in with the Idp and hasn't been removed from the SAML Application**. I would like to avoid redirecting the user to perform SSO again with IdP, because it would mean that if they are still logged in, they would be redirected back to the home page of my application. I wasn't able to find great sources on my options to go about it online.

### Questions:

1.1 One solution that comes to mind is storing the requested URL in the `RelayState` parameter, whenever the session has expired, then redirect the user to the IdP SSO URL. When the redirect returns to the SAML callback POST endpoint, check the `RelayState` parameter and if set, redirect back to that (original) URL. That means that for users that use the system continuously, I would have to request Assertions very often. Does that make sense?

1.2 A second solution that comes to mind is to implement a back-channel of communicating directly from my SP to the IdP. That would allow me to verify a user is still logged in 'behind the users back'. If that's a sound idea:

> a. Do I need to have dedicated code for each IdP?
>
> b. Do I need to load an API key to the IdP which would allow secure communication?
>
> c. Do I need to upload a public certificate to the IdP that would be able to verify that my SP signed the requests?

---

2. Will [using the Assertion to get an OAuth 2.0 Access Token](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55956_01/doc.11123/oauth_guide/content/oauth_access_token_saml.html) help me in achieving this?

---

3. I've chosen SAML 2.0 for now, since the environment is an enterprise oriented one and I thought it fits well with it based on what I read. Would using OpenID Connect instead help achieve my goals easier and fit well with enterprise oriented products?